# Notation for multiple elements not equal to each other

Tags: inequality, notation, article-writing

I have four elements, $A,B,C$ and $D$. I want to write that none of the elements are equal to each other. Basically, something like this:

$$A \neq B \neq C \neq D$$

However, this is incorrect, since $\neq$ is not transitive.

What would be an elegant and correct way to write this?

Comment: an elegant and correct way to write it can be: "four elements, A,B,C and D none of which are equal to each other"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no elegant symbolic way to do this with your set. If you instead have an indexed set $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$, you could say

> $$
> a_i\neq a_j \text{ when } i\neq j
> $$

or something to that effect.

But in your case I would just say

> I have four distinct elements $A, B, C, D$.

Maybe even go so far as saying "pairwise distinct".

Comment: Agree that "distinct" is the best choice. Is there any other interpretation of "distinct" that would make "pairwise distinct" necessary?

Comment: @GregMartin I don't know of one. But I have seen "pairwise distinct" written out before. So while the word might not have another meaning, some might want to be more explicit about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it if the number of items is small enough that you can count them. You can organize the items into a set and then insist that the cardinality of that set is the same as the number of symbols.

$$ |\{ A, B, C, D \}| = 4 $$